# Why dont work jquery functions after fill table with ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, top: 50, left: 350, height: 400 });

            $(".tbllist .malzlist").mouseover(function () {
                $(".tbllist .malzlist").css("background-color", "white"); //this function dont work
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

            });


            $(".tbllist .malzlist").dblclick(function () { //this function dont work

                var malznumber = $(this).children().first().text();
                $("#txtMatnr").val(malznumber);
                $.colorbox.close();

            });


            $('#txtMatnr').keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {

                    var MalzNo = $('#txtMatnr').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default2.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
                        async: false,
                        data: "{MalzemeNo:'" + MalzNo + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                            $.each(objdata, function () {
                                $(".tbllist > tbody:last").append('<tr class="malzlist">');
                                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                                    $(".tbllist tr:last").append("<td>" + v + "</td>");
                                });
                                $(".tbllist > tbody:last").append("</tr>");
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    $(".inline").click();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My table lines after ajax call;

```
<table class="tbllist">
<tr class="malzlist"><td>000000000000000018</td><td>upa1</td></tr>
<tr class="malzlist"><td>000000000000000018</td><td>upa1</td></tr>
</table>
```

When I fill table with ajax call ,two function(I write with comment) dont work,I think page dont see inserted  line by ajax call.When I fill table directly in html(without ajax call), Its workCan you help me please?

Comment: You're right the problem is that whenever you bind the event, the elements don't exist yet, so no event is bound to them.
That's typically a situation where you should use "Delegated events" , as explained in [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any content that is dynamically loaded into the page will not have event listeners applied to them. The way to get around this is by applying the  listeners to the `document` like so:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.tbllist .malzlist', function(){
   $(this).css("background-color", "white");
   $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});

$(document).on('dblclick', '.tbllist .malzlist', function(){
   var malznumber = $(this).children().first().text();
   $("#txtMatnr").val(malznumber);
   $.colorbox.close();
});
```

Do this with your other functions and they should work as well. Here is some more in depth information on the `.on()` method, and event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/ Hope this helps!